# Picking balls from a bowl

Tags: probability

Iv'e got a pretty basic probability question, and my suggested idea which is wrong according to the textbook.

> Assuming we have 10 balls, 7 of them or white and 3 of them are black. We randomly pick 4 balls (and not put them back). What is the probability that we picked at least 2 balls?

My solution:

Let $A_0$ be the event where zero black balls were picked
Let $A_1$ be the event where 1 black ball was picked. Then we are looking for $(A_0\cup A_1)^c$ hence $ 1 - P(A_0) - P(A_1) $

Then $ P(A_0) = \frac{7}{10}*\frac{6}{9}*\frac{5}{8}*\frac{4}{7}=\frac{1}{6}$

And $ P(A_1) = \frac{7}{10}*\frac{6}{9}*\frac{5}{8}*\frac{3}{7}=\frac{1}{8}$

But $1-\frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{8}$ is not the answer, which is $\frac{1}{3}$. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the question mean to ask about $2$ "black" balls?  Assuming you did...Your computation for $P(A_1)$ is incorrect  as you are (inappropriately) assuming that you draw the black one last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Required Probability $$= \dfrac{{7\choose 2}{3\choose 2}+{7\choose 1}{3\choose 3}}{{10\choose 4}} = \frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

When computing $P(A_1)$ you are assuming that the black ball has to be picked last.
But this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is $\frac13$. It is calculated as follows:

$1-\frac{\binom{7}{4}}{\binom{10}{4}}-\frac{\binom{7}{3}*\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{10}{4}}=\frac13$